# Angular + NodeJS HTTP error: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse"

Tags: node.js, json, angular, http

Hi can anybody help with the error: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse" - I've narrowed it down to the following.

Server side code:

```
                var response = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {

                    var fileName = // fetches correct filename from somewhere

                    response.push({
                        fileName: fileName,
                        fileSize: // fetches correct filesize from somewhere
                    })
                }

                res.status(200).json(response);
```

Client:

```
    public getFilesFromMeetingId(_meetingId: string) {
        return this.http
            .get<FileModel[]>('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/meeting/' + _meetingId + '/files')
    }
```

FileModel:

```
export class FileModel {

    constructor (
        public filename: string,
        public fileSize: number
    ) {}

}
```

getFilesFromMeeing code:

```
files: FileModel[];
  
  constructor(private fileService: FileService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileService.getFilesFromMeetingId(this._meetingId)
      .pipe( take(1) )
      .subscribe(
        filesResponseData => {
            this.files = filesResponseData;
        }
  );
  }
```

The odd thing is all my code works as intended, the FileModel picks up the HTTP response and parses it correctly but I assume my error is somewhere in how the server packages the response and how the JSON is converted to the FileModel object on the client side?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call `getFilesFromMeetingId` ? Can you please show that part ?

Comment: Added it to the original post. Thank you.